# Difference between Netty's ByteBuf.copy() and ByteBuf.duplicate()

Tags: java, netty

At first glance, they seem quite similar. My understanding is that `copy()` creates a copy of the underlying content whereas `duplicate()` does not. Is that accurate? In what situations would you use one vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**copy()**

> Returns a copy of this buffer's readable bytes. Modifying the content of the returned buffer or this buffer does not affect each other at all.

**duplicate()**

> Returns a buffer which shares the whole region of this buffer. Modifying the content of the returned buffer or this buffer affects each other's content while they maintain separate indexes and marks. This method does not modify readerIndex or writerIndex of this buffer.

When you want completely independent copy of a ByteBuf object you use copy() method.

More information can be found from [ByteBuf documentation](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html)